# Using polyfit to plot scatter points with errors

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I can use np.polyfit to fit a line in my scatter plot as shown bellow

```
a = np.array([1.08,2.05,1.56,0.73,1.1,0.73,0.34,0.73,0.88,2.05])
b=np.array([4.72131259,  6.60937492,  6.41485738,  6.82386894,  6.20293278,  7.22670489, 6.15681295,  5.91595178,  6.43917035,  6.64453907])

m1, b1 = np.polyfit(a, b, 1)
corr1 =a1.plot(a, m1*a+b1, '-', color='black')
a1.scatter(a, b)
```

[image]

Is there any way to fit a line using polyfit this time taking the errors for my points as shown bellow?

```
ae = np.empty(10)
ae.fill(0.15)
be = ae

sca1=a1.errorbar(a, b, ae, be, capsize=0, ls='none', color='black', elinewidth=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the fit and plot the (fixed at the given value) error bars over the fit points, like this:

[image]

Then this code will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp


a = np.array([1.08,2.05,1.56,0.73,1.1,0.73,0.34,0.73,0.88,2.05])
b=np.array([4.72131259,  6.60937492,  6.41485738,  6.82386894,  6.20293278,  7.22670489, 6.15681295,  5.91595178,  6.43917035,  6.64453907])

ae = np.empty(10)
ae.fill(0.15)
be = ae
m1, b1 = np.polyfit(a, b, 1)
mp.figure()
corr1 =mp.errorbar(a,m1*a+b1,ae,be, '-', color='black')
mp.scatter(a, b)
mp.show()
```

If you want to get the covariance of the fit, and use the standard deviation to set the error bars, instead use the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import math


a = np.array([1.08,2.05,1.56,0.73,1.1,0.73,0.34,0.73,0.88,2.05])
b=np.array([4.72131259,  6.60937492,  6.41485738,  6.82386894,  6.20293278,  7.22670489, 6.15681295,  5.91595178,  6.43917035,  6.64453907])

coeff,covar = np.polyfit(a, b, 1,cov=True) 
m1= coeff[0]
b1= coeff[1]
xe = math.sqrt(covar[0][0])
ye = math.sqrt(covar[1][2])

mp.figure()
corr1 =mp.errorbar(a,m1*a+b1,xe,ye, '-', color='black')
mp.scatter(a, b)
mp.show()
```

which gives a plot like this:

[image]

If you want to do a weighted fit, you can supply a weight vector to polyfit with the syntax

> m2, b2 = np.polyfit(a, b, 1,w=weightvector)

According to the documentation the weightvector should contain 1 over the standard deviation of the data points.

If you want to do a least squares fit weighted by errors in BOTH x and y, I don't think polyfit does this - it will accept a weight vector for one dimension.

To supply errors in both dimensions as weights you would have to use **scipy.optimize.leastsq**.

There is a documentation page at [this link of the Scipy documentation](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData) about doing fits with **scipy.optimize.leastsq**. The example talks about a fit to power law, but clearly a straight line could be done as well.

For errors in one dimension (Y) here, an example using leastsq is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import math
from scipy import optimize 

a = np.array([1.08,2.05,1.56,0.73,1.1,0.73,0.34,0.73,0.88,2.05])
b=np.array([4.72131259,  6.60937492,  6.41485738,  6.82386894,  6.20293278,  7.22670489, 6.15681295,  5.91595178,  6.43917035,  6.64453907])
aerr = np.empty(10)
aerr.fill(0.15)
berr=aerr

# fit a straight line with scipy scipy.optimize.leastsq    
# define our (line) fitting function
fitfunc = lambda p, x: p[0] + p[1] * x
errfunc = lambda p, x, y, err: (y - fitfunc(p, x)) / err

pinit = [1.0, -1.0]
out = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, pinit,args=(a, b, aerr), full_output=1) 
coeff = out[0]
covar = out[1]
print  'coeff', coeff
print 'covar', covar
m1= coeff[1]
b1= coeff[0]
xe = math.sqrt(covar[0][0])
ye = math.sqrt(covar[1][1])

# plot results
mp.figure()
corr2 =mp.errorbar(a,m1*a+b1,xe,ye, '-', color='red')
mp.scatter(a, b)
mp.show()
```

To take into account errors in both X and Y, you would have to change the definition of errfunc to reflect the specific technique you are using to do that. If a lambda isn't convenient you can instead define a function that will do that. I can't comment further on this without knowing what technique is being used to weight by X and Y errors, there are several in the literature.

Comment: Is the fitted line actually taking into account the errorbars for the scatter points?

Comment: No, it's using your fixed error bar values and plotting over. I'll need to edit if you want the fit errors. I think you can get those values from polyfit however.

Comment: If you want to do a weighted fit, you can supply a weight vector to polyfit with the syntax m2, b2 = np.polyfit(a, b, 1,w=weightvector). According to the documentation the weightvector should contain 1 over the standard deviation of the data points.